# Single user not receiving e-mails regarding Alerts

Tags: permissions, alert

I am having a minor issue related to a single user on my Sharepoint Server 2010 setup.

I have a single user who does not receieve Alerts, neither when creating an alert, or in cases where the user is expected to receieve alerts.

It *does* work on My Sites, and we have done tests on all groups to ensure that other users are indeed receiving alerts, which they all do.

The user who experiences the problems have been taking part in setting up the primary webapplication and sitecollection, but is now a normal user. And for some reason this user has never been receiving e-mail notifications.

**My question**:

What process can I go through to check what might be wrong with the user, or is there a way I can ***completely delete*** the user, so all his rights are reset, and the user is recreated via our User Profile Synchronization process ?

Look forward to your advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would check their profile to make sure their email address is populated when the User Profile Sync takes place. If it is not, then you will need to ensure this data is entered into the appropriate AD field to populate. Next, I would check out their permissions to the site, because you can theoretically set up an alert for someone on a site, but if they do not have permissions (at least read) they will not receive the alerts. Next, I would check to see if the web app where they are not able to receive alerts from has a different From address than the others, and then check to see if the user has a rule or a junk mail filter set up for this address. Usually if other people are receiving alerts, and the user can receive alerts from other sites, then it is either permissions or a rule or filter.

Comment: I checked that the e-mailaddress exists, works, and that the e-mailaddress is populated correctly - All looks good and functions as expected and looks like any other user. Next I checked the from-address, which is also not the case, since it works for other users on the WebApp - I also checked that the e-mails didn't go into their spam-folder.

I believe it to be a permissions issue. But I can't seem to be able to completely delete the user, thus resetting their permissions to regular user rights, which works for all other users.

Comment: Their permissions are not tied to their user profiles. Just the information contained within them is pulled from that location. To delete the user from the permissions of the site, you can go view their effective permissions and completely remove them from all groups that have been granted permissions and remove their individual permissions.

Comment: You could completely remove the account from AD, and then manually delete their profile/mysite and then thye would have no permissions to the site, then create a new account and sync and add the person to the appropriate groups for permissions to the site. Then you can set up a new alert and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

First place to check is to make sure the user has a valid email account.  It amazes me how often this gets cleared out accidentally or on purpose.

Comment: The e-mailaddress exists and functions as expected

Answer (score -1):

You may need to force the Outlook integration with SharePoint. This will create a SharePoint list in Outlook.

[image]

Steps:

1. Browse to the list/document library
2. Select Actions
3. Select Connect to Outlook

   [image]
4. Select Allow
5. Select Yes